# how to binaries the image, assign the zeros and one into 2D image by a threshold point using python and convert it to RGB?

Tags: python, matlab, opencv

I have written the following code in MATLAB and want to convert it into python code. How can we find the MatLab instruction into python:

MatLab Code:

```
path = 'C:\Users\hp\Desktop\output\result_0.png';
img = imread(path);
size(img)
img = rgb2gray(img);
size(img)
m = mean(img(:));
img = img>m;
RGB = cat(3, img, img, img);
size(RGB)
```

Code in Python:

```
path = r"C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\output\\result_0.png"
img = cv2.imread(path)
print(img.shape)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
result = gray.flatten()
m = statistics.mean(result)
print(m)
gray = gray>m
img = gray.astype(int)
print(img)
cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

how to correct the python code, so that it works as MatLab code?

I am getting the error after running the python code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/pytorch-GaitGAN-master/src/test2.py", line 24, in <module>
    cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.0.0) c:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.hpp:261: error: (-2:Unspecified error) in function '__cdecl cv::CvtHelper<struct cv::Set<1,-1,-1>,struct cv::Set<3,4,-1>,struct cv::Set<0,2,5>,2>::CvtHelper(const class cv::_InputArray &,const class cv::_OutputArray &,int)'
> Unsupported depth of input image:
>     'VDepth::contains(depth)'
> where
>     'depth' is 4 (CV_32S)
```

---

the following code, I was required:

```
    import cv2
    import numpy as np

    path = r"C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\output\\result_0.png"
    img = cv2.imread(path)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray[gray<np.mean(gray)] = 0.
    gray[gray>=np.mean(gray)] = 255.
    print(gray.shape)
    img = np.stack((gray,)*3, axis=-1)
    print(img.shape)
    cv2.imshow('image',img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: I don't understand the: "convert element into zero from 2D matrix" could you give more info please

Comment: ok, I changed the title

Answer (score 1):

Based on your Matlab code, I think you want to threshold you image based on the mean value `m`. You can use [`cv2.threshold`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#gae8a4a146d1ca78c626a53577199e9c57) to do this.

```
img = cv2.imread(path)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
result = gray.flatten()
m = statistics.mean(result)
gray_thres = cv2.threshold(gray,m,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
```

You may need to change the value 255 to the max value in your image. More info [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html).